# C# Regular Expression-Special characters

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have below mentioned regular expression which will identify the following special characters:

```
~!@©#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?`€[]\;',./
```

The regex:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"[\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{P}\p{S}]");
var str = "~!@©#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?€[]\\;',./`éöò";
var all = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().ToList();
```

How can I exclude a literal dot character (`.`) in above regular expression as I need to validate a price value like "`16.01`" which is valid (dot is valid in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\p{P}` contains the `.` symbol, thus, it is matched.

You can subtract the dot from the character class if it is no longer a "special" char for your case, and other punctuation symbols in your list are:

```
[\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{P}\p{S}-[.]]
```

And then `16.01` will not match.